# Disable keyboard functionality for window support flutter app

Tags: flutter, keyboard, disable

> How can I disable soft keyboard which is always shown in window support flutter app.
> If click on the keyboard >close functionality, it shows at another page again.
> Any suggestion will helpful for me for resolving this issue for >window support flutter app.

\>I  tried gesture detector like given below:-

> GestureDetector(
> onTap: () {FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
> if
>
> ```
> ( !currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();}}`
> ```